# Simultaneous looping

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to make a basic simple game in C++ where the user constantly needs to input, and there should be constant output of other things (a moving object(*)).

Even if the user doesn't input anything, the object must keep moving. This needs two loops to be run simultaneously which I don't know how to do.

There is no graphics just basic symbols and letters.

Comment: Use a terminal library such as `ncurses`. You can have a polling event loop waiting on `STDIN_FILENO`; no need for threads.

Comment: Question/requirements not really clear.

Comment: i am a newbie to programming using TC is there a way to input and output different thing simultaneously?

Comment: ^this question makes me think you plain out didn't read the comments, or chose to ignore them. Did you bother at least googling for "thread"?

Comment: yes its a third party library but i told that i dont know much c++ it is my 4th month in c++ in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two simultaneous loops.  You should have only a single loop.  On each loop iteration, you will update your game's output and then *check* if the user has entered any input.  If he has, then you read it and process it; otherwise, you just continue with your next loop iteration.  An easy way to get started it to use the _kbhit and _getch functions, but you'll probably need to use something more advanced like ncurses or the Win32 console functions eventually.

```
while( !gameOver ) {
    DisplayGameState();

    if( _kbhit() ) {
        int c = _getch();
        ProcessInput( c );
    }
}
```